# How to read file type by using FileReader interface in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi how to ready file type input while submitting a form.
my html is like this.

```
<input type="file" name="attachment[]" class="">
<input type="file" name="attachment[]" class="">
<input type="file" name="attachment[]" class="">
```

I am using this code inside form submit function

```
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {

    var files = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='attachment']").files;

    if (files.length>0) {
        // CODE HERE
    }
}
```

But on if condition it is always showing me files is not define.

Comment: There are plenty of file reader examples to find using google.

Comment: but why it is giving me error of not define.

Comment: 1. You query `input[name='attachment']` while you should use `input[name='attachment[]']`, but 2. a collection of nodes won't have a shared `.files` property, you should loop over the inputs and process `.files` property of each one separately.

Comment: Your selector is maybe not valid. I've never sued such selector, but you maybe have to write attachment[] and not just attachment. You should select your inputs by using a class or any other selector that you are absolutly certain to work.

Comment: The selector is wrong, a collection of DOM nodes has no `files` property, and unless you're running this on an event, like change etc. and not on pageload, there won't be any files ?

Comment: 1. I have used attachment[] but no luck and 2. I understand your words that nodes wont have .files property then how to loop over file type inputs cause I am using this code inside a submit function. I can not use change event inside that function.

Comment: google + querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You query `input[name='attachment']` while you should use `input[name='attachment[]']`, but
2. a collection of nodes won't have a shared `.files` property, you should loop over the inputs and process .files property of each one separately:

_

```
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='attachment[]']");
    for( var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
        console.log( inputs[i].files );
        // process the files of input i
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3mwan/